# Visual Studio 2019 Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: visual-studio

Getting this message when I open visual studio 2019, newly installed. Tried window repair, uninstall / reinstall... I have not found anything recent on this particular issue.

> SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.IsPreviewChannel()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.PreviewFeatures.UsePreviewSdk.Initialize()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.CommonIDEStatics.Initialize()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.BasePackage.d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.CommonIDEPackage.d__20.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.d__76.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()

Comment: Have you tried launching it as Administrator?

Comment: Run as administrator, Installed as admin

Comment: And it still throws the same error when you run as administrator?